# How do I add classes dynamically in React 16+?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple a React application, and I would like to add classes dynamically in my components.

Note: I am using React 16.6.3.

Here is what I have tried:

Layout component

```
import React from 'react';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from './Layout.css';
const layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop </div>
        <main className={classes.Content}>
        {props.children}
        </main>
    </Aux>
);

export default layout;
```

Here's what I have in `Layout.css`:

```
.Content{
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: green;
}
```

Unfortunately when I run the application no classes is added to my div `main`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<main className="Content">`

Comment: This depends on what your build setup is. If you're using a build process that supports CSS Module syntax, then your code should work. Otherwise, @Keith has the correct answer. What build process are you using (did you use `create-react-app`, do you have a custom Webpack build config, etc.)?

Comment: @Keith that is not dynamically, that is static way, I need to do as I showed in code, problem it does not work , I odnt what am I missing

Comment: @err1100 here is my repo u can check it I have those config file ,  by running npm run eject u will have a config file in your app  https://github.com/throne1986/burger

Comment: If your using CSS modules, then here your not making any locals,  so in you CSS if you do  `:local(.Content) {` does it work?   ps, using `className` can certainly be dynamic.. :)

Comment: It looks like you’ve ejected from CRA. In that case, you should just be able to rename Layout.css to Layout.module.css and it should work. You may need to do `import * as classes` instead of just `import classes`.

Comment: @Keith ur wrong that is not dynamic in any shape or form . please check my repo and react doc about css modules u will understand what I mean , u have many ways of implemeting classes in react one is this I am using in my app , just check docs about css modules my brother u will get it

Comment: @err1100 why layout.module.css? any docs on this?? I odnt get it . let me try

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree, React everything is dynamic.  I use dynamic className props all the time.   So the any shape or form, is totally off base.  css modules is just one way of doing things, it's not the only way.

Comment: @err1100 That worked like charm  brother , hoho, please give me some knowleadge on why we should add module to css file name to make it works, thanks a lot , el perfecto, add that as answer I will accept ASAP.

Comment: @Keith maybe ur right , thanks for sharing your knowledge though , I apreciate a lot

Comment: @user9964622, this is just a convention that CRA has defined - CSS modules modules should be named `.module.css` or `.module.sass`. If you search your ejected Webpack config, you’ll see the regex in the CSS loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention in CRA, CSS modules should be named with `.module.(s)css`. So just change the name of `Layout.css` to `Layout.module.css`. You’ll also need to change the import to `import * as classes` since the build process does not generate a default export.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables for a class with properties. The name for the component need to be capitalised. Layout.

Example:

```
const Layout = (props) => (
<Aux>
    <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop </div>
    <main className={props.customClass}>
    {props.children}
    </main>
</Aux>
```

When yo call your component, yuo can do it like this:

```
<div>
   <Layout customClass="dynamic-class" />
</div>
```